# How can I make this more robust, given that there is no reflection in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
T get_value(std::string name, T defaultValue)
{
  // read values from config file and assign to var; if not found use defaultValue
  return defaultValue;
}

class A {
public:
  A()
    : myvar1_(get_value("myvar1", 0))
    , myvar2_(get_value("myvar2", 1.5))
  {
  }

  int myvar1_;
  double myvar2_;

  std::string asString() const {
    std::stringstream str;
    str << "myvar1 = " << myvar1_
        << ", myvar2 = " << myvar2_;
    return str.str();
  }
private:
  // other things exist here, unrelated to myvar1/2
};
```

Where `get_value` is a function that reads the values of the variables from some config file, and if not found uses the default value. I also have `myvar1_` and `myvar2_` as public member variables, because they get accessed directly, and I'd like to keep that feature and do not want to add a potential function hop.

Now, you can see that I have typed `myvar1` or `myvar1_` in quite a few different places, and I'd like to make this more robust, so that I can type, somewhere somehow, `myvar1_, "myvar1", 0` **once** (as opposed to having typed `myvar1_` 3 times and `"myvar1"` twice), and automagically get the above functions called and values filled. I have a lot of variables and they get added or removed fairly frequently, and sometimes I forget to initialize them, or mistype the string name in `set_value`, or forget to add a new variable to `asString`.

Is that possible to do? I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: There is no way the above code can compile by adding more code.  You have simplified down to invalid code. Please provide valid code, it makes misunderstandings less likely.  As an example, I cannot tell if default init followed by reading from file is acceptable or not.  If your code was valid, I would have at least a clue.

Comment: @Yakk modified it to be compilable and to reflect actual code more closely

Comment: @eddi: So your question is... how to aggregate together a value and a string name?

Comment: @NicolBolas how to aggregate the 3 together (value, string name, default value), maintain direct access to member variables (or some other equivalent thing that is strictly not worse performance-wise), and have the ability to list all variables

Comment: @eddi: The default value is only used in one place, so it's value is irrelevant. But if you really want to bloat your data, you can stick it in the struct. If "direct access" is really that important to you, make them public members. As for the latter, that wasn't part of your question.

Comment: @NicolBolas well that's just one way I'm imagining implementing the constructor and `asString` - point is I don't want to type "myvar1_" and "myvar1" more than once in this class; but as-is I've typed "myvar1_" 3 times and "myvar1" twice.

Comment: Tuple of tuple of (member function ptr, name, default value).  But construting is tricky.  Can have data be part of anonymous union of variable and aligned storage.  Presume equal, or add aligned storage ptr to tuple.  Write for-each-tuple-element, iterate to construct with exception care to destroy proper elements.  Printing similarly.  Lots of boilerplate, reusable mostly, only justified if common pattern or really really large type.  Alternative is C style macro magic.

Comment: Are you using C++11 or later?

Comment: I really think you are asking if a method for serializing c++ structs/classes exists.  I would say check out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/

Comment: I would love language features to make classes serializable. As it is there's a lot of uglification involved. Libs like boost::serialize reduce this to a minimum but it would be nice to go further.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson I looked at a few examples in there, and it doesn't look like the number of times I'd have to type `myvar1/myvar1_` would decrease

Comment: There are a number of libraries already existent for config file parsing that you may find easier to use. [This overview](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3021.pdf) provides some ideas, but is from 2011 so there may be newer, better ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a macro solution, heavily borrowing from a different SO answer:

```
#define EVAL0(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EVAL1(...) EVAL0 (EVAL0 (EVAL0 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1 (EVAL1 (EVAL1 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL3(...) EVAL2 (EVAL2 (EVAL2 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL3 (EVAL3 (EVAL3 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL4 (EVAL4 (EVAL4 (__VA_ARGS__)))

#define MAP_END(...)
#define MAP_OUT

#define MAP_GET_END0() 0, MAP_END
#define MAP_GET_END1(...) 0

#define GET_MACRO(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, NAME, ...) NAME
#define MAP_GET_END(...) GET_MACRO(_0, ##__VA_ARGS__, MAP_GET_END1, MAP_GET_END1, MAP_GET_END1, MAP_GET_END1, MAP_GET_END0)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MAP_NEXT0(item, next, ...) next MAP_OUT
#define MAP_NEXT1(item, next) MAP_NEXT0 (item, next, 0)
#define MAP_NEXT(item, next)  MAP_NEXT1 (MAP_GET_END item, next)

#define MAP0(f, x, peek, ...) f(x) MAP_NEXT (peek, MAP1) (f, peek, __VA_ARGS__)
#define MAP1(f, x, peek, ...) f(x) MAP_NEXT (peek, MAP0) (f, peek, __VA_ARGS__)

#define MAP(f, ...) EVAL (MAP1 (f, __VA_ARGS__, (), 0))


#define DEFINE_VARS_T(TYPE, NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE) \
  TYPE NAME##_;
#define DEFINE_VARS(TUPLE) DEFINE_VARS_T TUPLE

#define CONSTRUCT_VARS_T(TYPE, NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE) \
  NAME##_ = get_value(#NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE);
#define CONSTRUCT_VARS(TUPLE) CONSTRUCT_VARS_T TUPLE

#define PRINT_VARS_T(TYPE, NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE) \
  << #NAME << " = " << NAME##_ << ", "
#define PRINT_VARS(TUPLE) PRINT_VARS_T TUPLE

#define CONFIG_VARS(...) \
  MAP(DEFINE_VARS, __VA_ARGS__) \
  A() { \
    MAP(CONSTRUCT_VARS, __VA_ARGS__) \
  } \
  std::string asString() const { \
    std::stringstream str; \
    str MAP(PRINT_VARS, __VA_ARGS__); \
    return str.str(); \
  }

template <typename T>
T get_value(std::string name, T defaultValue)
{
  // read values from config file and assign to var
  return defaultValue;
}

class A {
public:
  CONFIG_VARS
  (
    (int, myvar1, 0),
    (double, myvar2, 1.5),
    (std::string, myvar3, "what")
  )

private:
  // other things exist here, unrelated to myvar1/2
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: A DSL that generates your code from definitions.

Option 2: Use a class facade over the config lookup, backed presumably by access to your config class, and combine with C++11's member initialization. This will reduce the number of times you have to repeat a variable, which can then be hidden with a little macroing if you're up for that.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class DV {
    T value_;
public:
    DV(const char* name, const T& defaultValue)
    {
        // read values from config file and assign to var; if not found use defaultValue
        value_ = defaultValue;
    }

    operator const T& () const { return value_; }
};

using DVInt = DV<int>;
using DVStr = DV<const char*>;

struct A {
    int i_ = DVInt("i", 42);
    const char* str_ = DVStr("str", "hello");

    A() = default;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.i_ << ", " << a.str_ << "\n";
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/RAyKwI

-- Edit --

Reducing to one instance with a macro.

Instead of the `using` statements:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class DV {
    T value_;
public:
    DV(const char* name, const T& defaultValue)
    {
        // read values from config file and assign to var; if not found use defaultValue
        value_ = defaultValue;
    }

    operator const T& () const { return value_; }
};

#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define DVDecl(T, name, def) T CONCAT(name, _) = DV<T>(#name, def)
#define DVInt(name, def) DVDecl(int, name, def)
#define DVCStr(name, def) DVDecl(const char*, name, def)

struct A {
    DVInt(myvar1, 42);
    DVCStr(myvar2, "hello");

    A() = default;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.myvar1_ << ", " << a.myvar2_ << "\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/JmgfH9

This doesn't eliminate your need to manually add them to `asString`, though.

Comment: Wait. Does your example solve anything? To add a member to `A` is to duplicate typing out its type and name in its `to_string`-like (that is, you'd still need to add `float b_ = DVFloat("b",0.123);` *and*  `... << a.b_ ...` to `main`.) I think the goal would be to, in *one place*, define names, types, and defaults, and have valid a valid struct, constructor, and (verbose) to_string. (Also, in your example, do you just throw out the string name of the var? what's the point?)

Comment: @Phildo In the OPs code, he's having to repeat the names in the ctor for A. I've eliminated that by using the DV struct. You can eliminate the duplication of the name in the member declaration with a macro that expands to include the definition, bringing you down to having to type it once.

Comment: wait- why even have the `const char *name` in the first place? what's its purpose?

Comment: @Phildo wait - maybe you should read the OPs question so you know what I'm answering?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do this I'm afraid. The simplifications I made to the OP hid the fact, that in the real world the config reader function that I use is actually passed to me in the constructor..